# How can I use the Gradle Copy task to rename a directory on the path of a file I am copying?

Tags: gradle, groovy, copy

### Background

I have a Gradle Copy task like this:

```
task copyFromZip(type: Copy) {
    from zipTree("Example.zip")
    into "build/output"
}
```

Within the Zip file is something like this:

```
+--- photos
|    +--- StackOverflow
|         \--- foo.png
|    \--- Super User
|         \--- bar.png
+--- text
|    \--- Stack Exchange
|        +--- StackOverflow
|             \--- foo.txt
|        \--- Super User
|             \--- bar.txt
```

When I run the Copy task, the directories are preserved. For instance, I have `build/output/photos/StackOverflow/foo.png`.

### Goal

What I want to do is rename the directories as I copy. For instance, say I realized that "StackOverflow" should have spaces in it. I want the file `photos/StackOverflow/foo.png` to be copied to `build/output/photos/Stack Overflow/foo.png`, and the same to be applied to the files in other folders with the name "StackOverflow" instead of "Stack Overflow".

### What I've tried

My first thought was to add a `rename{}` block.

```
task copyFromZip(type: Copy) {
    from zipTree("Example.zip")
    into "build/output"
    rename { String filePath ->
        filePath.replace("StackOverflow", "Stack Overflow")
    }
}
```

However, I discovered that `rename{}` only gives the name of the file, not the path.

I also tried manipulating the `relativePath` using `eachFile{}`

```
task copyFromZip(type: Copy) {
    from zipTree("Example.zip")
    into "build/output"
    eachFile{ file ->
        file.relativePath = file.relativePath.replace("StackOverflow", "Stack Overflow")
    }
}
```

However, that results in a `Could not expand ZIP` error.

How can I use the Gradle Copy task to rename a directory on the path of a file I am copying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `eachFile` or `filesMatching`, which gives you access to all the details of the source path and of the destination path. For example:

```
task copy(type: Copy) {
    from zipTree("Example.zip")
    into "build/output"
    filesMatching("**/StackOverflow/**/*") {
        it.path = it.path.replace("StackOverflow", "Stack Overflow")
    }
}
```

Comment: for me `eachFile` worked better. It moved the files. `filesMatching` copied the files.